# How load Partial View with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I have JavaScript to load a partial view.

```
<p>
    <div id="AREA_PARTIAL_VIEW">

    </div>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Content("Insert", "Customers","Insert_Partial_View")';
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(@MyChoise, "Corr_Exit"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
               </html>     etc...........
```

I'd load this partial between `<div>` tag

```
<div id="AREA_PARTIAL_VIEW">

</div>
```

But my code doesn't work. Why?

Someone can help me please?

Comment: "doesn't work" is awfully broad. What do you mean? Also, your code is going to redirect the browser to the URL you're putting in there. If you want to load something, use jQuery's [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function...

Comment: What do you think `window.location.href = ` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used load ajax for this

```
$('#AREA_PARTIAL_VIEW').load('@Url.Action("Insert_Partial_View","Customers")');
```

Comment: You have been very helpful ...! Thank you very much..